# Defining multiple parent xpath in the class method

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have defined two parent XPath in the **init** something like this below:

```
def __init__(self, driver, fieldName):

        self.driver = driver

        try:
            try:
                self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='quickeditfrm']//tr/th/label[text()='%s']" % fieldName)
            except:
                self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(QuickEditLocatars.ROWPARENT % fieldName)

        except:
            try:
                self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(QuickEditLocatars.ROWPARENT % (fieldName + ":"))
            except:
                self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='quickeditfrm']//tr/th/label[text()='%s']" % (fieldName + ":"))
```

But i am in the situation where I have to work with three parent xpath. The parent xpath is different depending on the pages. But each page will not have the all three xpath. It will only have one parent xpath.

I know I can use try and except but having two or more parent xpath makes it difficult to maintain the code and makes it messy. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is to *concatenate the XPath expressions* using the "|" (means "or") operator:

```
def __init__(self, driver, fieldName):
    self.driver = driver

    expressions = [
        "//form[@name='quickeditfrm']//tr/th/label[text()='%s']" % fieldName,
        QuickEditLocatars.ROWPARENT % fieldName,
        QuickEditLocatars.ROWPARENT % (fieldName + ":"),
        "//form[@name='quickeditfrm']//tr/th/label[text()='%s']" % (fieldName + ":")
    ]
    self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(" | ".join(expressions)
```

You may need to add a single try/except to handle the "negative" case when the element was not found by any of the expressions at all.

Comment: great. one last question what is the use of pipe here?

Comment: @user7242550 sure, it basically means logical "or".